# Opencv - How to differentiate jitter from panning?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a **video stabilizer** using Opencv in C++.
At this time of the project I'm correctly able to find the translation between two consecutive frames with 3 different technique (Optical Flow, Phase Correlation, BFMatcher on points of interests).
To obtain a stabilized image I add up all the translation vector (from consecutive frame) to one, which is used in `warpAffine` function to correct the output image.

I'm having good result on fixed camera but result on camera in translation are really bad : the image disappear from the screen.

I think I have to distinguish jitter movement that I want to remove from panning movement that I want to keep. But I'm open to others solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you the possible approaches (in complexity order):

- apply some easy-to-implement IIR low pass filter on the translation vectors before applying the stabilization. This will separate the high frequency (jitter) from the low frequency (panning)
- same idea, a bit more complex, use Kalman filtering to track a motion with constant velocity or acceleration. You can use OpenCV's Kalman filter for that.
- A bit more tricky, put a threshold on the motion amplitude to decide between two states (moving vs static camera) and filter the translation or not.
- Finaly, you can use some elaborate technique from machine Learning to try to identify the user's desired motion (static, panning, etc.) and filter or not the motion vectors used for the stabilization.

Just a threshold is not a low pass filter.
Possible low pass filters (that are easy to implement):

- there is the well known averaging, that is already a low-pass filter whose cutoff frequency depends on the number of samples that go into the averaging equation (the more samples the lower the cutoff frequency).
- One frequently used filter is the exponential filter (because it forgets the past with an exponential rate decay). It is simply computed as `x_filt(k) = a*x_nofilt(k) + (1-a)x_filt(k-1)` with `0 <= a <= 1`.
- Another popular filter (and that can be computed beyond order 1) is the [Butterworth filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter).
- Etc [Low pass filters on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter), [IIR filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response)...

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.
Can you tell me more about the first approach ? 
Is a simple `ìf` enough to make a low pass filter ? That's what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the whole problem is a bit more complex than you might have thought in the beginning. Let's look a it this way: when you move your camera through the world, things that move close to the camera move faster than the ones in the background - so objects at different depths change their relative distance (look at your finder while moving the head and see how it points to different things). This means the image actually transforms and does not only translate (move in x or y) - so how do you want to accompensate for that? What you you need to do is to infer how much the camera moved (translation along x,y and z) and how much it rotated (with the angles of yaw, pan and tilt). This is a not very trivial task but openCV comes with a very nice package: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html

So I recommend you to read as much on Homography(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography), camera models and calibration as possible and then think what you actually want to stabilize for and if it is only for the rotation angles, the task is much simpler than if you would also like to stabilize for translational jitters.

If you don't want to go fancy and neglect the third dimension, I suggest that you average the optic flow, high-pass filter it and compensate this movement with a image translation into the oposite direction. This will keep your image more or less in the middle of the frame and only small,fast changes will be counteracted.